# $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective cogenerator of $\mathbb{Z}-Mod$

Tags: modules, injective-module

Let $R$ be a ring. An injective left $R$-module $E$ is called an injective cogenerator if $Hom_R(M,E) \not =0$ for $0 \not =M \in R-Mod$.

I have seen that $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective cogenerator of $\mathbb{Z}-Mod$(here $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the ring of rational numbers and $\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the ring of integers): Since $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is divisible as $\mathbb{Z}$-module and all divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are injective, we have $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is injective. Then how to get that $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is a cogenerator?

Comment: Can you show that $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(A,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ is nonzero when $A$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Not quite.  Since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, every ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $a\mathbb Z$, and the map sending $1$ to $a$ is an isomorphism between $\mathbb Z$ and $a\mathbb Z$.  Alternatively, every subgroup of a free group is free.  In either case, $\ker f$ is free, so $\hom(\ker f,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ will be a direct product (not necessarily sum if no longer finitely generated) of copies of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. However, we aren't dealing with vector spaces, and so even if the "rank" were the same, injective and surjective maps wouldn't necessarily be the same thing.

Comment: For example, the map $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z $ defined by $x\mapsto 2x$ is surjective (because $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z $ is divisible) but not injective (because $1/2$ maps to $0$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61134/discussion-between-aaron-and-penson).

Comment: @Aaron Actually, we don't need to show that $Hom(A,Q/Z) \not =0$ for all finitely generated modules $A$. We just only need to show that $Hom(S, Q/Z) \not = 0$  for all simple Z-modules $S$. We can get this by the way we use above: Since $S$ is simple ,there is an epimorphism $f: Z \rightarrow S$. Then since $kerf$ is a left ideal of $Z$, it it of the form $kerf =bZ$ for some $b \in Z$. Now the natural embeding $i : bZ \rightarrow Z$ can't induce an isomorphism $Hom(i,Q/Z): Hom(Z, Q/Z) \rightarrow Hom(bZ,Q/Z)$. For example, take $f:Z \rightarrow Q/Z$ as f(x)=x/b, then the composition $f i =0$

Comment: @Aaron If $M$ is an injective $Z$-module and $Hom(S,M) \not =0$ for all simple $Z$-mdoule $S$, then $M$ is an injective cogenerator. Hope no mistake this time.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that I wanted you to reduce the problem to the f.g. case, I thought that, in the f.g. case you can appeal to the structure theorem for f.g. modules to get a more hands on/computational perspective that might be insightful.  I don't off the top of my head see why you can reduce to the case of simple modules (as a non-finitely generated module such as $\mathbb Q$ need not split as a direct sum of simples, so there isn't an obvious way to extend a map from a submodule to the entire module in a controlled way), but if you have the reduction I would love to see it.

Comment: @Aaron  This is a conclusion of the book “Rings and category of modules”, on page 211, it say that for an injective module $E$ over a ring $R$,  $E$ is a cogenerator iff $Hom_R(T,E) \not =0$ for all simple $R$-modules $T$ iff $E$ cognerates every simple $R$-module.